# Unable to use any user in laravel project other than the root

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, environment-variables

I am a beginner developing an app in Laravel framework. I am facing a problem that only the root user works with my database without the password or the user ''@'host' works. However, when I deploy the app to the server I can not use any of these users

I get the following error, it seems that the Laravel is not reading any user name from .env or database.php file. (as the name of the user is blank here).

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'itax'

Again it works if I use the user=root and no password or user=''

Here are the configurations of my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=itax
DB_USERNAME=raees
DB_PASSWORD=12345
```

and database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'itax',
        'username'  => 'raees',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Anyone facing the same issue or found any solutions to these problems please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution with empty username. The username was always blank.

The issue was with MySQL. The SQLSTATE error message is being passed directly from MySQL.

So then I deleted the database and user. Re-created the database in the Databases tab of PhpMyAdmin. And importantly separately added the user and privileges. This fixed the issue.

I could connect from the MySQL client and run migrations.